# Clean install still loads old data

Tags: macos, high-sierra, disk-utility, install

A while back I erased the HDD on my old iMac, without installing a new OS.

Today, I plugged in a bootable High Sierra USB and installed that on it. I expected it to be a clean install, but somehow all my old files are there. I didn't even have to create a new user account as my old one still appeared to be active.

It's a good job I didn't give it away to anyone or sell it.

I think I noticed a 'recovery' partition when I went to boot from the USB, could this have happened because of that? Is there a way I can just erase all my old data and start afresh?

Comment: Simply erasing a HD does not actually remove any data, only the pointers to where it is. This however, does not mean it will be found again by simply installing a fresh new OS, you would have to make a concerted effort to recover it. Therefore, there is some error in your method or description of it.

Comment: Have you tried the security wipe? Seven passes or even more with 1’s and 0’s ?

Comment: *How* did you erase the HDD?  What command(s) and/or procedures did you do?  @Tetsujin is correct, especially with respect to recovery. There’s no data recovery provision in the macOS install.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I ended up giving it another shot by booting from my USB and *then* erasing the drive through disk utility... originally I just booted up with `CMD+R` then formatted the drive and left it. It seems strange that that didn't work the first time round, it's as if I need to boot from a bootable USB just in order to format the HDD properly (hope that makes sense)